# How to export a 3D map into a image file?

Tags: qgis, export, 3d, visualisation, nviz

With qgis, it seems to be possible to visualize 3D with two tools : nviz and Qgis2threejs.

But i would like export the result into an image file. Is it possible to do that with qgis?

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit why print screen of Qgis2threejs is not sufficient?

Comment: Because, in a 2nd time, after exportaing, i would like import the image result into adobe illustrator in order to add information, labelling,etc.

Comment: You can do that in Python

Comment: That still does not explain to me why you can't simply save as image the scene generated by Qgis2threejs. Simply print screen or there are also some plugins for all major browsers to capture the content and save as image in preferred image format and some advanced even allow to save image in specified (higher than screen) resolution. Also Qgis2threejs has already pretty good options for labeling, have you tried to label points etc. directly through it?

Answer (score 3):

When showing the data in 3D using Qgis2threejs, click on SHIFT+s, and a "save as" window will appear. It has limited options as you can see below, but you can change the width and height as desired. The output file will be in PNG format.

[image]